# How to check against the contents of an arraylist then get the value of another element of the arraylist

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist

I have a GUI that takes user input. With that input I am adding it in to an arraylist that is assigned to a class. So I need certain elements to make sure it fits the constructor. However, the input doesn't have everything I need to fit the constructor. I need to be able to see if one part of the users input is the same as something that I already have in the arraylist. If it does match then I will need to get the price from that object to use to populate the constructor. Below is the actionlistener code that I currently have;

submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

```
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                String data[];

                String data1[];
                double price;
                String cType;
                if((CustomerTest.courseList.contains(courseBox.getSelectedItem().toString())))
                {
                    return CustomerTest.courseList.get(2);
                }
                data = startDateField.getText().split("/");
                data1 = endDateField.getText().split("/");

                Course course1 = new Course(courseBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), instructorField.getText(),**price** **This is the variable I need from the arraylist as prices will be the same for the classes**, new Date(Integer.parseInt(data[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(data[1]),Integer.parseInt(data[2])),new Date(Integer.parseInt(data1[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(data1[1]),Integer.parseInt(data1[2])));
                CustomerTest.courseList.add(course1);
                for (Course c: CustomerTest.courseList)
                    System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information to help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe using a for loop over the ArrayList ? You may also try to debug it with some outputs :

> e.g. System.out.println(courseBox.getSelectedItem().toString());

```
for(int i = 0; i < CustomerTest.courseList.size(); i++) {
    if((CustomerTest.courseList.contains(courseBox.getSelectedItem().toString()))){
    return CustomerTest.courseList.get(2);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it gave me an error code of :

Comment: MenuTest.java:359: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
                                                        return CustomerTest.courseList.get(2);

Comment: How about, without the return value ?

Comment: I am not sure what to set it to, because when I did price = CustomerTest.courseList.get(2);. It came back with an error

Comment: I don't know the type of courseList, but you need to cast the type of courseList.get(2); , too double for price.  price = (double) CustomerTest.courseList.get(2); .